# Получение значения переменной по адресу указателя

Tags: c#, указатели

Есть метод, на вход в котором помимо прочего передаётся параметр param2 типа int, который, согласно описанию метода, является *Pointer to the 32-bit logical variable (LongBool)*. Требуется получить значение логической переменной, используя этот параметр. Я никак не могу понять, как это сделать. Пробовал писать, например,
 `bool* a = (bool*)&param2;`
, но значение получается всегда true. Как правильно узнать значение переменной?

Код метода:

```
            /// <summary>
            /// Реализация интерфейса IAimpMessageHook.
            /// 
            /// При получении определённых сообщений от плеера генерируем события.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="message"></param>
            /// <param name="param1"></param>
            /// <param name="param2"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public AimpActionResult CoreMessage(AimpCoreMessageType message, int param1, int param2)
            {
                // воспроизведение началось
                if (message == AimpCoreMessageType.AIMP_MSG_CMD_PLAY ||
                        message == AimpCoreMessageType.AIMP_MSG_EVENT_STREAM_START)
                {
                    OnPlay();
                }
                // воспроизведение остановлено вручную или закончился плейлист
                else if (message == AimpCoreMessageType.AIMP_MSG_CMD_STOP ||
                        message == AimpCoreMessageType.AIMP_MSG_EVENT_STREAM_END)
                {
                    OnStop();
                }
                else if (message == AimpCoreMessageType.AIMP_MSG_PROPERTY_REPEAT)
                {
                    unsafe
                    {
                        // тут нужно узнать, включился режим повтора или выключился
                        bool* a = (bool*)&param2;
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Repeat: {0}", a->ToString());
                    }
                }
                return AimpActionResult.OK;
            }
```

В явном виде в коде этот метод нигде не вызывается.
Меня интересует свойство AimpCoreMessageType.AIMP_MSG_PROPERTY_REPEAT. Это элемент перечисления AimpCoreMessageType:

```
    //
    // Сводка:
    //     Track repeat state. Param1: Access direction: Read / Write (AIMP_MSG_PROPVALUE_GET
    //     / AIMP_MSG_PROPVALUE_SET) Param2: Pointer to the 32-bit logical variable (LongBool).
    //     Value: False / True Default: False
    AIMP_MSG_PROPERTY_REPEAT = 4116,
```

При нажатии на кнопку включения/выключения повтора в плеере вызывается данный метод с параметрами:

`message = AIMP.SDK.MessageDispatcher.AimpCoreMessageType.AIMP_MSG_PROPERTY_REPEAT
param1 = 1
param2 = 1702224`

Comment: А можно метод и его вызов увидеть?

Comment: @ЖекаДиулин, дополнил вопрос

Comment: Так ведь у тебя вроде как параметр param2 был указателем, а теперь int почему-то. Я конечно понимаю, что это может друг в друга преобразовываться, но наверное чтобы передать указатель, стоит использовать тип указателя.

Comment: И второй момент. Это снова выгдядит так, будто ты берёшь адрес параметра param2, преобразовываешь его к указателю на буль, а потом сохраняешь. И конечно же в 255-и из 256-и случаев это будет true! потому что всё, что не ноль - это true.

Comment: Щас попробую у себя в вижуалочке

Comment: Кстати,  возможно LongBool - это некий отдельный тип. Ибо если бы это был указатель на буль - то было бы просто bool*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Там же сказано:

> Pointer to the 32-bit logical variable (LongBool)

Не надо ничего ни к чему приводить, или пытаться взять адрес, просто проверяйте так:

`result = param2 != 0;`

Ну а если вы на 100 процентов уверены что там адрес **указателя** на булевую переменную (и вы не собираете проект под 64 битные системы), то так:

```
bool val = *(bool*)(int*)param2;
```

P.S. [LongBool](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.LongBool).

Answer (score 0):

Ну, как я понимаю:

```
bool b = false; // Переменная
bool* p = &b;   // Указатель, который указывает на переменную b. 
                // &b - взятие адреса
bool b2 = *p;   // в переменную b2 будет передано значение, на которое указывает p
                // *p - разыменование, т.е. взятие значения по адресу
```

Так что думаю, в вашем случае надо делать так:

```
bool a = *param2; // записываем в а значение по указателю param2
```

, а не:

```
bool* a = (bool*)&param2; // АДРЕС УКАЗАТЕЛЯ на искомое значение,
                          // явно преобразованный к указателю на буль
```

Если возникают сложности с передачей указателя в метод, то пометьте весь класс словом unsafe:

```
unsafe class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool a = false;
        bool* pa = &a;

        Console.WriteLine(*pa);
        takeABoolPointer(pa);

        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }

    static void takeABoolPointer(bool* pointer)
    {
        bool a = *pointer;
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
```

Пробуй.

Comment: Если написать bool a = *param2;, то среда подчёркивает эту строку и выдаёт сообщение: К указателю должен быть применён оператор * или ->.

Comment: Так блин. Я не успеваю за твоими правками. Конечно, ты ведь тут в буль это сохраняешь. И в таком случае указатель на буль надо разыменовать, чтобы получить значение по указателю... Блин, сложно звучит, будешь долго переваривать

Comment: Сейчас дополню свой ответ

Comment: Проверяй. Если это не заработает, то это порча, сходи к бабке